# Given a source and destination, find the path with minimum stress level in a Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs, dynamic-programming, recurrence-relation, dijkstras-algorithm

I faced this problem in a hiring challenge which is now over.
I wrote a solution for the problem but at that time the judge gave me wrong answer. Afterwords I thought about the solution but couldn't find any problem with my logic. Maybe I made some implementation mistake during the contest (I'm not sure). But now I have my solution and I don't know if it's correct or not. I have tried it on multiple graphs and it gives correct answer on all of them. But yes a single case is enough to prove an algorithm wrong. So below I provide the details. Please help me validate the solution.

**Problem**
Given an **un-directed graph (can be disconnected)** with **N nodes** and **E edges**. The **stress level** of the path is defined as the **maximum weight of an edge present on this path**. Given a source **U** and destination **V** you need to tell the **minimum stress level** from node U to node V. **If you cannot reach V from U, return -1.**

**My Solution**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define int long long

const int mod = 1e9 + 7;

int minStressLevel(vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > &adj, set<pair<int, int> > 
&visited, int src, int dst) {
    if(src == dst) return 0;

        int ans = INT_MAX;
        for(auto to: adj[dst]) {
        int v = to.first;
        int w = to.second;

        if(!visited.count({dst, v})) {
            visited.insert({dst, v});
            visited.insert({v, dst});
            ans = min(ans, max(minStressLevel(adj, visited, src, v), w));
        }
    }

    return ans;
}

int32_t main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;

    for(int d = 0; d < t; d++) {
        int n, e;
        cin >> n >> e;

        vector<vector<pair<int, int> > > adj(n + 1);

        for(int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
            int u, v, w;
            cin >> u >> v >> w;

            adj[u].push_back({v, w});
            adj[v].push_back({u, w});
        }

        vector<int> dp(n + 1, INT_MAX);
        set<pair<int, int> > visited;

        int source, destination;
        cin >> source >> destination;

        int ans = minStressLevel(adj, visited, source, destination);
        cout << "Case #" << d << ": ";
        if(ans == INT_MAX) cout << -1 << endl;
        else cout << ans << endl;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**
The solution is based on this recurrence:
minStressLevel(V) = min{max(minStressLevel(K), edge_weight(K, V))} over all neighbours K of V.

I keep a set of pairs to keep track of what edges have been visited so that I don't get into infinite loops. **This is different than a simple Breadth First Search where we stop once we discover a vertex and do not visit it again.**

**Time Complexity**
I think time complexity is O(E), where E is the number of edges.
**Constraints**
N <= 1e5
E <= 1e5
edge_weight <= 1e9

Comment: Checking your code is off-topic here.  Coding questions are off-topic here, and not everyone knows C++, so we request people to use concise pseudocode rather than providing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your algorithm is correct, but keep in mind that I haven't read your code carefully; consider replacing the code with pseudocode.

One solution that could work in $O(m \log m)$ time is to binary search for the stress level and do BFS on only edges with lower weight.

Comment: Yes you are right, the algorithm is incorrect, I was working on it and found the same. Infact the output of algo depends on order of edges. By the way, In you answer do I have to check for connectivity after binary search's check function ? Also do you think it can be dijkstra ?

Comment: I am saying dijkstra because consider the recurrecnce minStressLevel(V) = min{max(minStressLevel(K), edge_weight(K, V))} over all neighbours K of V. It is very similar to shortest path recurrence dist[v] = min(dist[u] + edge_weight(u,v))

Comment: You can use dijkstra if you want, but bfs and in fact DFS too will work. Since you only traverse the weights smaller than a threshold, you only care if u and v are in the same component.